# How to hide View in Browser in document library in sharepoint 2010 using javascript or jquery

Tags: sharepoint

I had integrated Office Web Apps in sharepoint 2010. When Document is selected from document Library in context menu I want to hide Option View in Browser and Edit in Browser Option from Document Library.

Is is possible using jquery or javascript If yes can any tell me how ?
I used following css to hide but it only hide Delet option not View in Browser Option

```
li.ms-MenuUIULItem[text~=Delete]
        {
            display: none;
        }
```

So I also Modified it as follows

```
li.ms-MenuUIULItem[text~=View&nbsp;in&nbsp;Browser]
        {
            display: none;
        }
```

It also didn't work.
Can anyone help me for that ?

Comment: If possible, Can you provide me the screen shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created it using jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){            

        $('.ms-MenuUIPopupBody').live('blur', function() {       
           var elm = $("div.ms-MenuUIULItem a:contains('View in Browser')"); 
           elm.remove();     
           $("div.ms-MenuUIULItem a:contains('Edit in Browser')").remove();  
         });
});
```

It is hiding menu only on focus or blur or mouseover

I wants it to be hide on load AS soon as i Click on "V" option on right side of document it should hide View in Browser and Edit in browser

When I click on V option ![I wants As soon as i Click on v option right side of test it should hide view in Browser and edit in browser][1]

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do it with features than doing it with javascript.

You have to create a feature with a `HideCustomAction` element in it.
The element structure is like this:

```
<HideCustomAction
  GroupId = "[GroupId]"
  HideActionId = "[HideActionId]"
  Id = "...."
  Location = "....">
</HideCustomAction>
```

And here is a link that will help you find your required actions Id:

http://www.sharepointarchitects.us/johnholliday/post/0001/01/01/how-to-find-customaction-identifiers/